# 400 error on login

Tags: craft3

When I try to login to my admin area, I get this error:
HTTP 400 - Bad Request - yii/web/BadRequestHttpException
Unable to verify your data submission.

The login button stays faded out, but it usually turns red once I type in the username/password. Front-end of the site is working just fine.

I've tried clearing my cache/cookies and using a completely different browser/computer, but it's still giving me that error.

Stack trace:

```
2018-12-04 11:43:49 [-][-][hms8j39h5es918dp04hkjcmjs1][error][yii\web\HttpException:400] yii\web\BadRequestHttpException: Unable to verify your data submission. in /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Controller.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(83): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#1 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(155): craft\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction))
#2 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(104): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#3 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#4 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(282): yii\base\Module->runAction('users/login', Array)
#5 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(542): craft\web\Application->runAction('users/login', Array)
#6 /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(266): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#7 /vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#8 /index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! Just renamed `cpresources` folder to `cpresources2` (could also have deleted it, I suppose), cleared my cache, and now I can log in.